# using knockout to create a slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am learning in using knockout and what I am doing now is creating a Slider using `jquery ui slider`.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.slider = {
  init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    var options = allBindingsAccessor().sliderOptions || {};
    $(element).slider(options);
    ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "slidechange", function (event, ui) {
        var observable = valueAccessor();
        observable(ui.value);
    });
    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
        $(element).slider("destroy");
    });
    ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "slide", function (event, ui) {
        var observable = valueAccessor();
        observable(ui.value);
    });
  },
  update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    if (isNaN(value)) value = 0;
    $(element).slider("value", value);

  }
};
```

In my slider, there is 3 states: 0, 50 and 100 which should be set according to the value of A in my `ViewModel`

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.A = ko.observable(null);

    var x = Math.random();
    if(x<0.33){
         self.A(0);

    }else if (x>0.33 && x<0.66){

         self.A(50);
    }else {
         self.A(100);

    }

}
```

And in reverse, when we change the slider in the `View`, the parameter A in the `ViewModel` should be changed also.

This is my View:

```
<div style="margin: 10px" data-bind="slider: A, sliderOptions: {min: 0, max: 100, step: 50}"></div>
```

I already successful to create the slider with these three states according to the value of A, but when I change the slider, the new value of A in the `viewModel` is not updated. Can anyone have an idea?

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dt7Ka/446/).

Comment: [If tweaked your jsfiddle works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/18jzuvcd/) (though I felt the example was clearer with `step: 10` and no `afterkeydown` updating). So it's unclear to me what you're asking exactly.

Comment: Hi Jeroen, I am sorry because of making you confused. I already updated again to make my question clearer. About the question:  'Why do you pass sliderOptions through allBindingsAccessor and not slider` itself?' . I have no idea because I just found the code of the slider in the internet.

Comment: @Jeroen: *"Why do you have `if: $root.A`, since `A` is an observable shouldn't it be `A()`?"* KO will unwrap the value if it's an observable. It's normal in bindings to write the observable without the `()` on it, and sometimes (two-way bindings, so not `if`) it's necessary to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted in your question is working as intended when properly combined. Here's an example, that adds a small `pre` tag which shows the current state of the `$root` view model at any given time. When you change the slider you'll see that the observable tags along as intended.

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.slider = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    var options = allBindingsAccessor().sliderOptions || {};
    $(element).slider(options);
    ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "slidechange", function(event, ui) {
      var observable = valueAccessor();
      observable(ui.value);
    });
    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
      $(element).slider("destroy");
    });
    ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "slide", function(event, ui) {
      var observable = valueAccessor();
      observable(ui.value);
    });
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    if (isNaN(value)) value = 0;
    $(element).slider("value", value);
  }
};

var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.A = ko.observable(null);

  var x = Math.random();
  
  if (x < 0.33) {
    self.A(0);
  } else if (x > 0.33 && x < 0.66) {
    self.A(50);
  } else {
    self.A(100);
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.2.1/knockout-min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />Value:

<div style="margin: 10px" data-bind="slider: A, sliderOptions: {min: 0, max: 100, step: 50}"></div>
<hr>Debug info: <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```